# Impact of the channel length on the threshold voltage in CMOS transistor?

Tags: transistors, cmos, physics

Is there a monotonic relation between the channel length and threshold Voltage and is it proportional or inverse?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is - yes.

The slightly longer answer, it depends on the fabrication details of the transistor and it's targeted use case.

In all cases, below a critical length \$V_{TH}\$ decreases with decreasing length.  However once this critical length is met the \$V_{TH}\$ can increase, stay the same or decrease.  Here are some pictures.

[image]
image 1: flat

[image]
image 2: decreasing

[image]
image 3: increasing

There is also a correspondance between Gate Oxide thickness, the S/D structure design  and this critical length.

Comment: Does it have any closed form mathematical relation?

Comment: I've not seen any, just collections of points.  Good question BTW.  It might be difficult though as what dominates below critical length is different than what dominates above it. All though I suspect that perhaps Vittoz/Enz charge based transistor models might be able to do this.

Comment: would you please include the references to your curves?

Comment: The first from the internet, the others are internal and anonymized from different processes, i.e. not available.

Comment: please specify the CP full expression in your answer.